# PHPExcel Incorrectly Zipping xlsx

Tags: php, excel, moodle

I have an application (Moodle derivative) that uses PHPExcel. Recently, the export of *.xlsx files has started going wrong. If I open the file in Linux's Archive mounter and extract it, and then rezip by using

```
find -type f | xargs zip ../file.xlsx
```

it works, but before this, it is gobbledegook in Excel, LibreOffice etc.

I don't know what has changed. Could it be that the server's PHP zip function is doing something wrong?

Comment: I'd check nothing has changed on your server in terms of the PHP zip module. Has PHP been upgraded? Do you have access to the server configuration to check PHP version, php-zip module installation, etc?

Comment: @fred2 Thanks. Yeah - that was on my list but it's not as simple as it sounds. I suppose I'm hoping that someone will say, Oh yeah, I've seen this before, it's caused by ....

Comment: Sorry not to be more help. PHPExcel can be fiddly, but mod-zip, or something to do with it, is quite likely to be the issue. What happens when you use a non-zipped format like xls? Appreciate that's not a solution, but might give a further hint. Another thing that can cause problems is unexpected output, like a PHP error, which PHPExcel tries to write to an Excel file.

Comment: @fred2 Thanks Fred. I'll get the sysadmins to look into that stuff. Cheers.